# Redux-Toolkit = can't display API Response Data by using useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I try to create the filter form by using react hook form for filter the stockMovement report.The flow is user fill up the filter form  and click the filter submit button to dispatch filter value to getStockMovement function for call the API and I successful get the API response data but can't display the response data to my interface by using useSelector. I have put the reducer and component code below.

> reportStockMovementSlice Code

```
    import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, createSelector} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    export const getStockMovement = createAsyncThunk('report/stockMovement/getStockMovement', async( params,{dispatch})=> {
        const {by} = params;
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8100/getpickuppointbyid/pickupPointId={"pickupPointId":${by}}`);
        const data = await response.data.results[0];
        console.log("getStockMovement",data) --- response data successfull
         return data === undefined ? null : data;
    });
    
    const reportStockMovementSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'report/stockMovement',
        initialState:{
            stockMovement:[] },
        reducers: {},
        extraReducers: {
            [getStockMovement.fulfilled]: (state, action) =>{
             state.stockMovement =action.payload;}}
    });
    
    export const selectStockMovement = createSelector(
        (state) => ({
           stockMovement:state.stockMovement
        }), (state) =>  state
      );
   export default reportStockMovementSlice.reducer;









>  StockMovementFilter Component Code
>         
>         import { getStockMovement, selectStockMovement  } from '../store/reportStockMovementSlice';
>         const result= useSelector(selectStockMovement);
>         console.log ("result---",result)   - undefined 
>      function StockMovementFilter(props) {   
>          /// button submit pass filter values to API
>         function submit (){
>         
>          dispatch(getStockMovement(getValues())).then(action=>{
>           console.log ("---action---",action) --- this have response result
>          })
>             console.log ("-----value",getValues()) - this value get from react hook form
>         }
       }
  export default withReducer('report', reducer) (StockMovementFilter);




> --- main stockMovementReport 
>     function StockMovementReport() {
>       return (
>           
>           <FusePageCarded
>               classes={{
>                   content: 'flex',
>                   // contentCard: 'overflow-hidden',
>                     toolbar: 'min-h-56 h-56 items-end',
>                   header: 'min-h-52 h-52 sm:h-136 sm:min-h-136'
>               }}
>               // header={<StockMovementHeader />}
>               content={<div> <div className="row"><StockMovementFilter/></div> <div
> className="row"><StockMovementTable /></div> </div>}
>               innerScroll
>           />
>       
>       );
>     }
>     
>     export default  withReducer('report',reducer) (StockMovementReport);
```

store combine

```
import reportStockMovement from './reportStockMovementSlice';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    reportStockMovement 
});

export default reducer;
```

witReducer code

```
import { injectReducer } from 'app/store/index';

const withReducer = (key, reducer) => WrappedComponent => {
    injectReducer(key, reducer);

    return props => <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
};

export default withReducer;
```

Comment: How did you set up your store? Can you please share that code, too?

Comment: @phry Hi, ok. I shared part of code above.

Comment: @phry the redux devtools show report-> reportStockMovement -> stockMovement ：{ "name":"yyy")

Comment: @phry but I tried export const selectStockMovement = state=>state.report.reportStockMovement.stockMovement;  also cannot ( undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Your path to your store data is wrong.

A selector always selects from the root state of your store - and in your case, you just have more nesting.

I would recommend you to use the Redux Devtools to see how your store is nested, but from your `combineReducers` call, I would assume that the path to your data is something like `state.reportStockMovement`, so you would want to do something like

```js
    export const selectStockMovement = (state) => state.reportStockMovement.stockMovement
```

By the way, you don't need to use `createSelector` if you are really just selecting data from your store - only use that when you either have a complex calculation in there or return a new object, which in this case is probably not necessary.

I would recommend reading https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

Comment: the redux devtools show  reportStockMovement -> stockMovement ：{ "name":"yyy")